# Assigning colors to patches with no neighboring patches having the same color

Tags: netlogo

I'm a beginner, and I'm trying to generate a geographical space with three different colored patches. I'd also like for them to not be neighbors if they have the same color (for yellow and black) as that would make no sense in the model I'm working on. This is the code I've used so far

```
to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor green]
  ask n-of number-of-cities patches [
    set pcolor yellow]
  ask n-of number-of-coal patches [
    set pcolor black]
end
```

Again, I'd like black patches to not have any black neighbour, and the same for yellow.

Comment: `neighbors with [pcolor != [pcolor] of myself]`?

Comment: I can't understand how to plug in this code correctly but thank you, I'll keep working on it